# Unable to login in EC2 instance from github repo via gitaction

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with a downloaded repository that runs some commands via githubaction.
I get the following error and can't seem to understand what I need to do.

Here is my github action

```
name: Deploy to x-web

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Register Private Key
      uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.4
      with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
          
    - name: Deploy to EC2  
      env:
        HOSTNAME : XX.XX.X.XX
        USER_NAME : ec2-user
      run: |
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${USER_NAME}@${HOSTNAME} '
          cd ./x-web
          eval $(ssh-agent -s)
          ssh-add /home/ec2-user/.ssh/github
          git checkout -b foo
          git branch -D master
          git checkout -b master origin/master-f
          git fetch --all -f &&
          git pull origin master -f &&
          git branch -D foo
          npm i --force && npm run build &&
          pm2 restart Frontend
          '
```

The error that I get is the following ....

```
Agent pid 16351
Identity added: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/github (/home/ec2-user/.ssh/github)
fatal: a branch named 'foo' already exists
error: Cannot delete branch 'master' checked out at '/home/ec2-user/x-web'
fatal: a branch named 'master' already exists
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow what you are try to achieve, but to help you with a few of the errors:

`fatal: a branch named 'foo' already exists` is caused by your use of the `-b` flag which will attempt to create a new branch, but it looks like your repo has one already. Use `git checkout foo` instead to switch to it.

`error: Cannot delete branch 'master' checked out at '/home/ec2-user/x-web'` since your checkout failed you didn't switch off of master and you cant delete the branch you are on.

`fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address` I'm not 100% sure of but I suspect that in your manipulation of ssh or setting of env `HOSTNAME` or `USER_NAME` has caused this I would also recommend updating your first step to `actions/checkout@v3`

Answer (score 0):

If git version on your ECS is recent enough (2.23 or more), use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) instead of `git checkout`.

That way you can replace

```bash
git checkout -b foo
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master origin/master-f
```

with:

```bash
git switch -C foo
git switch -f -C master origin/master
```

Also check your `git remote -v` on that instance. If it starts with `https://`, your SSH key would not be used at all.

A `git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/` would help ensuring you are using SSH.
(Or, if you know the full URL, `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<user>/<repo>`)